# How to insert any string in sqlite3 in c

Tags: c, sqlite

I have to insert a string into a sqlite data base 
my command ..

```
Err=sqlite_exec(DB, "create table tbl5(TEXT varchar(100));", xCallback, (void*)"First Test", &ErrMsg);

Err=sqlite_exec(DB, "insert into tbl5 values  ('some string');", xCallback, (void*)"First Test", &ErrMsg);
```

works fine but when I want to put `s="some string"` ie

```
Err=sqlite_exec(DB, "insert into tbl5 values  (s);", xCallback, (void*)"First Test", &ErrMsg);
```

then this is not working so how to add  variable then It is not working so how to insert variable in sqlite database
thank u

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use `sprintf()` but `sqlite3_mprintf()`. [Here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html) is the documentation.

```
char s[20] = "some string";
char* query = sqlite3_mprintf("insert into tbl5 values ('%q');", s);
```

Otherwise you have a risk of [*SQL injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

The resulting query string should be freed using `sqlite3_free()`.

Also note the `'%q'` instead of the usual `'%s'`.

Comment: Interesting function, I didn't know it existed. I used sqlite3 in C++, using `std` functionality for building my queries. Hence, I wasn't aware of this C-oriented functionality.

Comment: @Pieter: Actually, I also use it in `C++`. The documentation of sqlite isn't really straightforward but it seems this is the only way of doing this safely.

Answer (score 3):

Other than the suggestions already given, you can also use prepared statements with bound parameters (this is also useful if you intend to repeat the statement several times with different parameters). see the [`sqlite3_prepare_v2`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) and [`sqlite3_bind_*`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) for more information

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

// Create a prepared statement.
Err = sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, "insert into tbl5 values (?)", -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (Err != SQLITE_OK)
{
    //...
}

// Bind our string to the statement.
Err = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "some string", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
if (Err != SQLITE_OK)
{
    //...
}

// Execute the statement.
Err = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if (Err != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    //...
}

// Free the prepared statement.
Err = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sprintf` to create a formatted string.

```
char s[20] = "some string";
char query[100];
sprintf(query, "insert into tbl5 values (%s);", s);
```

It's up to you to make sure `query` is big enough.

Comment: Using `sprintf()` here is probably a bad advice. See my answer for the "why".