# iPHONE SDK- sqlite , how do i do an insert statement

Tags: iphone

i have a database that is in the documents directorys of the 
Application/iPhoneSimulator/3.2/Applications/etc/Documents

I have this code under my method

```
    databaseName = @"database.sql";
NSArray *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory.NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
```

How do i do an insert with a variable/ array .
Something like
"INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN) VALUES ('%@'),[appDelegate.variable objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I insist you to go through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716839). 
First of all copy the database from main bundle to your application's document dir.
You can follow below code to implement it.

```
    NSString *databaseFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kDataBaseName ofType:kDataBaseExt];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSString *dbPath=[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",kDataBaseName,kDataBaseExt]];
    NSFileManager *fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]){
        [fm copyItemAtPath:databaseFile toPath:dbPath error:nil];
    }

    [fm release];

    self.dataBasePath=dbPath;
```

I am supplying you directly my project code. Please add comment if any doubts.
I have added comments for the explanation.

```
// function with multiple arguments which is going to be used for inserting into table.
+(void)insertBuilding:(NSString*)BName streetNo:(NSInteger)streetNo streetName:(NSString*)streetName streetDir:(NSString*)streetDir muni:(NSString*)muni province:(NSString*)province bAccess:(NSString*)bAccess bType:(NSString*)bType amnity:(NSString*)amnity latitude:(NSString*)latitude longitude:(NSString*)longitude imageName:(NSString*)imageName {
    // application delegate where I have saved my database path.
    BuildingLocatorAppDelegate *x=(BuildingLocatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    sqlite3 *database; // database pointer
    // verifying if database successfully opened from path or not.
    // you must open database for executing insert query    
    // i have supplied database path in argument 
    // opened database address will be assigned to database pointer.
    if(sqlite3_open([[x dataBasePath] UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // creating a simple insert query string with arguments.
        NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into buildingDtl(b_name,streetNo,streetName,streetDir,muni,province,b_access,b_type,aminity,latitude,longitude,b_image) values('%@',%i,'%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",BName,streetNo,streetName,streetDir,muni,province,bAccess,bType,amnity,latitude,longitude,imageName];
        // converting query to UTF8string.
        const char *sqlStmt=[str UTF8String];       
        sqlite3_stmt *cmp_sqlStmt;
        // preparing for execution of statement.
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStmt, -1, &cmp_sqlStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
            int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStmt, -1, &cmp_sqlStmt, NULL);
            ((returnValue==SQLITE_OK) ?  NSLog(@"Success") :  NSLog(@"UnSuccess") );
                // if NSLog -> unsuccess - that means - there is some problem with insert query.
            sqlite3_step(cmp_sqlStmt);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(cmp_sqlStmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    // please don't forget to close database.
}
```

Comment: Hi i tried this and had a success in the NSLOG. But however when i try to read the database again, the values werent there

Comment: databaseName = @"TestDatabase.sql";
 
 //Get the path to the documents
 NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
 
 UIAlertView *view;
 
 // Setup the database object
 sqlite3 *database; 
 appDelegate.dBCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 
 // Open the database from the users filessytem
 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

Comment: // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
  const char *sqlStatement = "Select EntryID From XMLEntryID ORDER BY xeID DESC LIMIT 1 ";
  sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
  
  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement,-1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
   // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
   while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    // Read the data from the result row
    NSString *aEntryID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];

Comment: // Add the user object to the users Array and respectively
    [appDelegate.dBCount addObject:aEntryID];
    view = [[UIAlertView alloc]
      initWithTitle: @"A Message"
      message: aEntryID
      delegate: self
      cancelButtonTitle: @"Yay.!" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [view show];
    [view autorelease];
    [aEntryID release];
    
    return;
   }
  }
  // Release the compiled statement from memory
  sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
  
 }
 sqlite3_close(database);

Comment: this is the code in my method to read the database for the latest value that i have, however it seems that the values weren't inserted .

Comment: Oh ! I knew that - you should open the database from documents dir. Go to UserName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.0/Applications/YourAppID/Documents/yourDB.sqlite  -> open this database & check weather inserted or not.

Comment: I am afraid you might be checking wrong database. Once you copy your database to application's documents directory - you should open & check it from there. Every time when you compile if documents directory doesn't contain database,then it should copy from the main bundle, main bundle should have empty copy of the database.

Comment: have you placed code for copying the database from main bundle to documents directory - or just pasted directly above code ?

Comment: iv check every database in my pc and there werent any new data  , below is the code for the inserting

Comment: //setup some globals
 databaseName = @"MedicalBedDatabase.sql";
 
 //Get the path to the documents
 NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

Comment: sqlite3 *database;
 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO XMLEntryID(EntryID) VALUES ('%@')",[appDelegate.xmlLastCount objectAtIndex:0]];
  const char *sqlStmt = [str UTF8String];
  sqlite3_stmt *cmp_sqlStmt;
  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStmt, -1, &cmp_sqlStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
     {
      int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStmt, -1, &cmp_sqlStmt, NULL);
      ((returnValue ==SQLITE_OK) ? NSLog(@"INSERT SUCCESS") : NSLog(@" INSERT Fail"));
      sqlite3_step(cmp_sqlStmt);
     }

Comment: sqlite3_finalize(cmp_sqlStmt);
  
 }
 sqlite3_close(database);

Comment: where do i implement that? in the appDelegate.m?

Comment: Ahhh :p it's up to your requirement. It's up to what you prefer. I prefer to place it on appDelegate.m - so, I placed there. Choice is up to you - where you save the database path string.

Comment: hmm i think im having the correct database path. However i tried inserting values into the table on the Terminal applications but returns me

SQL error: unable to open database file. 
Is it possible that the file is read-only? If so how can i change it

Comment: *UPDATE*
It works! i found out i was doign something silly in my method that caused the database to be locked

Answer (score 1):

```
+(NSString *)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format parameters:...];

NSString sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO table VALUES('%@')", @"Hello, world!"];
sqlite3_....
```

Comment: In that case you would want to escape your single-quotes by replacing them with double single-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use either prepared statements in combination with the [`bind_*()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) functions (e.g. `bind_text()`) or the [`mprintf()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html) function to insert strings, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942370/how-to-insert-any-string-in-sqlite3-in-c) for details.

To get a raw C-string you can pass to these functions use [`-UTF8String`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String) or [`-cStringUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/cStringUsingEncoding%3A) on a `NSString`.